# Confirm prompts failing to display

Tags: javascript, html

I have to make a guessing game for a course. However, even when I compare it to solutions, it seems fine. But it does not show anything in the browser.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Color Guessing Game</title>
  </head>
  <body onload="do_game()">
      <script type="text/javascript">
    var colors = ["blue", "gray", "yellow", "green","black", "cyan", "purple", "silver", "orange", "lime", "magenta", "olive", "maroon", "brown", "darkblue", "lightblue"];
          boolean finished=false:=;
          var target;
          var guess_input;
          var guess;

          function do_game(){
              random=Math.floor(Math.random()*colors.length);
              target=colors[random];

              var message: "I am thinking of one of these colors...\n"
              for (var i = 0 ; i < colors.length ; i++) {
                    message += colors[i];
                    if (i == (colors.length-2)){
                        message += " and finally ";
                    } else if (i != (colors.length-1)) {
                        message += ", ";
                    }
                }

              var guesses=0;
              var finished=false;
              alert(target);

              while(!finished){
                  guess_input=prompt(message).toLowerCase();
                  guess=guess_input;
                  guesses++;
                  finished=check_guess(guess,target);
              }
          }

          function check_guess(guess,target){
                if(guess>colors[target])
                    alert("I don’t recognize that color! Mine is higher alphabetically.")
                    return false;
                if(guess>colors[target])
                    alert("I don’t recognize that color! Mine is lower alphabetically.")
                    return false;
                if(guess==colors[target])
                    //background color, msg, nbr guesses
                    return true;
                else
                    //doesnt exist
                    return false;
            }
      </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Everything seems logical to me. However, as soon as I open the browser nothing happens. How come?

Comment: You have a variety of syntax errors. Open your developer's console (press F12 and click the "console" tab to see them listed.

Comment: Your `check_guess()` function isn't going to work the way you think, consider: https://jsfiddle.net/eh4tu1ev/

Comment: Thank you. I get  guess.html:10 Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier (i modified it to var finished = false; but it still won't work)
and
guess.html:7 Uncaught ReferenceError: do_game is not defined
    at onload (guess.html:7) I don't really know what to do about that

Answer (score 1):

`boolean finished=false:=;` is invalid syntax and should probably be:

```
 var finished = false;
```

and `var message: "I am thinking of one of these colors...\n"` has a colon instead of an equal sign and should be:

```
var message = "I am thinking of one of these colors...\n";
```

This will get your code running, although you still have **a lot** of work to do with it to make the logic work properly and to ensure it still works when users enter unexpected input.

You should always check your developer's console (press F12 and click to the "console" tab to see error messages).

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Color Guessing Game</title>
  </head>
  <body onload="do_game()">
  
      <script type="text/javascript">
      
    var colors = ["blue", "gray", "yellow", "green","black", "cyan", "purple", "silver", "orange", "lime", "magenta", "olive", "maroon", "brown", "darkblue", "lightblue"];
          var finished = false;
          var target;
          var guess_input;
          var guess;

          function do_game(){
              random = Math.floor(Math.random()*colors.length);
              target = colors[random];

              // You had a colon instead of an equal sign
              var message = "I am thinking of one of these colors...\n";
              for (var i = 0 ; i < colors.length ; i++) {
                    message += colors[i];
                    if (i == (colors.length-2)){
                        message += " and finally ";
                    } else if (i != (colors.length-1)) {
                        message += ", ";
                    }
                }

              var guesses=0;
              var finished=false;
              alert(target);

              while(!finished){
                  guess_input=prompt(message).toLowerCase();
                  guess=guess_input;
                  guesses++;
                  finished=check_guess(guess,target);
              }
          }

          function check_guess(guess,target){
                if(guess>colors[target])
                    alert("I don’t recognize that color! Mine is higher alphabetically.")
                    return false;
                if(guess>colors[target])
                    alert("I don’t recognize that color! Mine is lower alphabetically.")
                    return false;
                if(guess==colors[target])
                    //background color, msg, nbr guesses
                    return true;
                else
                    //doesnt exist
                    return false;
            }
      </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thank you. However, after modifying the message colon, the cod still won't display anything on a webpage. Anything else I haven't thought about?

Comment: If you run the code snippet I have above, you will see that it does work. Your code must not be identical to what I've posted. And, again, you need to check your developer's console to see what error messages you have.